# What does Unknown media type in type 'all/all' mean?

Tags: package-management

I reinstalled the Amarok player in my Kubuntu 14.04 because it seemed buggy. I noticed this in the terminal:

```
david@EMACHINE:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall amarok
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,715 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirror.lstn.net/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amarok i386 2:2.8.0-0ubuntu3 [5,715 kB]
Fetched 5,715 kB in 2s (2,611 kB/s) 
(Reading database ... 128504 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amarok_2%3a2.8.0-0ubuntu3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking amarok (2:2.8.0-0ubuntu3) over (2:2.8.0-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up amarok (2:2.8.0-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
```

Look at all the unknowns. Could these be the cause of the player not working correctly? How can I fix this if it is, an error?

Comment: Is it working properly after the reinstall?

Comment: @Lucio simply re-installing packages rarely fixes problems as reinstalling does not replace configuration files.

Comment: This question should not have been closed, as it is a useful source of information on this issue. Otherwise, just go ahead and close askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 31):

it is a bug, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shared-mime-info/+bug/289592

try

```
sudo rm /usr/share/mime/packages/kde.xml 
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

Comment: For me, the above throroughly broke an otherwise perfectly fine  Ubuntu 14.04.4 desktop install, to the point of not being able to access it from the unity log-on screen anymore.  After some groping "in the dark", I had to scratch-reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` from console. No biggy but beware nevertheless ...

Comment: @Cbhihe those command should not have "broke an otherwise perfectly fine Ubuntu 14.04.4 desktop install". Details please, if it were perfectly fine whey did you run these commands ? How did it break ? ubuntu-desktop is a metapackage and does not install any packages, so what else was installed ?

Comment: Why it did **spurred my curiosity** too.  I am stumped so far. Context ? I was busy w/ `sudo apt-get wireshark wireshark-doc` when I saw what OP described. I followed yr suggestion and then reversed it from my stored `kde.xml_bak`... _**bam!!**_ . Unity started unraveling before my eyes. I first lost Skype and Psensor in the unity bar, then all the rest including desktop icons. Had to reboot from terminal.  Reboot led to unity login loop... followed up by opening console (ALT+CTRL+F3) and desktop reinstall as said. As for `ubuntu-desktop` being a metapackage, it is a fact.

Comment: FYI: Works on Arch Linux as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the error means but I'll share with you what worked for me.

Basically just delete all the erroneous mime-types in the `kde.xml` file.

After that run:

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

The first two should look something like;

```
<mime-type type="all/all">
  <comment>all files and folders</comment>
  </mime-type>
  <mime-type type="all/allfiles">
  <comment>all files</comment>
</mime-type>
```

Do likewise with the rest, then logout/login as needed.

[Source](http://www.garyshood.com/unknownmedia/)